# Light composite fermion as a bound state formed by $SU(4)$ gauge force attractions

Tags: particle-physics, gauge-theory, representation-theory, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

In this paper https://inspirehep.net/literature/152400, in eq.(3.4), it claims that

the MAC (most attractive channel) in $SU(4)$ gauge theory will attract

fermions in $[1]_4$

and

fermions in $[3]_4$

to form a bonus state: a Dirac fermion.

**question 1** --- It looks that $[1]_4$ and $[3]_4$ both have fermionic statistics, would the bound states should be bosonic statistics? (Is there a mistake?)

about the composite fermion,

I was wondering whether the

**question 2** --- $$[1]_4  [3]_4 \sim  [1]_4 \times [3]_4\sim [4]_4$$ **should be a boson, rather than a Dirac fermion as a spacetime spinor?**

**question 3** --- $$[0]_4  [1]_4  [3]_4 \sim  [0]_4 \times [1]_4 \times [3]_4 \sim [0]_4 [4]_4$$ **should be a Weyl fermion as a spacetime spinor?**

[image]